# How to replace a particular string with another in UNIX shell script

Tags: shell, unix

Could you please let me know how to replace a particular string present in a text file or `ksh` file in the server with another string ?

**For example :-**

I have 10 files present in the path `/file_sys/file` in which i have to replace the word "BILL" to "BILLING" in all the 10 files.

Comment: Take a look at the `sed` and `awk` utilities. Start by reading their man pages.

Comment: Yes i tried with sed -i 's/BILL/BILLING/g' *  but i got the error sed: illegal option -- i

Comment: You local `man` page documents the `-i` flag and your `sed` command does not? That sounds _very_ strange...

Comment: Also tried with sed 's/BILL/BILLING/g' Example.txt > Exam.txt but the Exam.txt is empty :(

Comment: Are you maybe using OS X on a Mac? If so, use `sed -i.bak 's/something/else/'`

Comment: @MarkSetchell : I am getting the below error for this :
error sed: illegal option -- i

Comment: @MarkSetchell and all :
I tried by giving an enter at the end of BILL and it worked...
BILL was replaced with BILLING using the command 
sed 's/BILL/BILLING/g' Example.txt > Exam.txt

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

I created a file 'test' with this content: "This is a simple test". Now I execute this call to the `sed` command:

```
sed -i 's/ is / is not /' test
```

Afterwards the file 'test' contains this content: "This is not a simple test"

---

If your `sed` utility does not support the `-i` flag, then there is a somewhat awkward workaround:

```
sed 's/ is / is not /' test > tmp_test && mv tmp_test test
```

Comment: I tried with sed 's/BILL /BILLING /g' Example.txt
but it didnt work for me as the file Example.txt is still having the value 'BILL'

Comment: I added a workaround for your strange version of `sed`. Awkward, but working.

Comment: Oh, and another hint: your regex notation tries to replace the string `BILL `, not `BILL` (note the trailing blank (` `)). If your file does _not_ contain that blank, then the regex will not match and replace...

Comment: I'm sorry the space was my typo mistake..
i tried 
's/BILL/BILLING/g' Example.txt > Exam.txt
But the Exam.txt is blank

Comment: Yep, you cannot redirect the output of `sed` to the file you use as input because of how the utility works. That is why the `-i` flag was introduced which internally buffers the output. Without that flag being available you have to use the workaround I added to the answer.

Comment: I am redirecting the contents of the file Example.txt to Exam.txt with the replaced string

Comment: Is the file having both upper and lower cases ? as in BILL and bill /Bill/biLL @NeethuShaji

Comment: @AritraBhattacharya :
No only uppercase
i got the result BILL was replaced with BILLING 
had to Enter <-| post the word BILL

Comment: Please post your files content and anso the version of ed` you are using (`sed --version`).

Comment: @arkascha I tried by giving an enter at the end of BILL and it worked... BILL was replaced with BILLING using the command sed 's/BILL/BILLING/g' Example.txt > Exam.txt

Comment: Not required for me, by tests all were without, nevertheless they worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Please find the testing as well.

$ cat > file1

I am a BILL boy

```
sed 's/[[:alnum:]   [:cntrl:]   [:lower:]   [:space:]   [:alpha:]   [:digit:]   [:print:]   [:upper:]   [:blank:]   [:graph:]   [:punct:]   [:xdigit:]]BILL[[:alnum:]   [:cntrl:]   [:lower:]   [:space:]   [:alpha:]   [:digit:]   [:print:]   [:upper:]   [:blank:]   [:graph:]   [:punct:]   [:xdigit:]]/BILLING/g' file1>file2
```

$ cat file2

I am a BILLING boy

Comment: This will work irrespective of the position of the occurrence of the word BILL in your file.  @NeethuShaji

Comment: The txt file is having only BILL nothing else in that.
I tried by giving an enter at the end of BILL and it worked... BILL was replaced with BILLING using the command sed 's/BILL/BILLING/g' Example.txt > Exam.txt

Comment: But the above code will not require you to put enter :) . @NeethuShaji

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\bBILL\b/BILLING/g' file
```

For inplace:

```
sed --in-place 's/\bBILL\b/BILLING/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

A little `for` loop might assist for dealing with multiple files, and here I'm assuming `-i` option is not available:

```
for file in $(grep -wl BILL /file_sys/file/*); do
    echo $file
    sed -e 's/\bBILL\b/BILLING/g' $file > tmp
    mv tmp $file
done
```

Here's what's happening:
  `grep -w`          Search for all (and only) files with the word BILL
  `grep -l`          Listing the file names (rather than content)
  `$(....)`          Execute whats inside the brackets (command substitution)
  `for file in`   Loop over each item in the list (each file with BILL in it)
  `echo $file`     Print each file name we loop over
  `sed command`   Replace the word BILL (here, specifically delimited with word boundaries "\b") with BILLING, into a tmp file
  `mv command`     Move the tmp file back to the original name (replace original)

You can easily test this without actually changing anything - e.g. just print the file name, or just print the contents (to make sure you've got what you expect before replacing the original files).